# yum update returns "Metadata file does not match checksum"

Tags: redhat, yum

```
[root@someserver yum]# yum update
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
rhel-x86_64-server-5                                     | 1.4 kB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-5/primary                             | 3.4 MB     00:03     
rhel-x86_64-server-5                                                10025/10025
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-5                       | 1.4 kB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-5/primary               | 250 kB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-5/primary               | 250 kB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-5/primary               | 250 kB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-5/primary               | 250 kB     00:00     
Error: failed to retrieve repodata/f0************************************************74-primary.xml.gz from rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-5
error was [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
[root@someserver yum]#
```

google says:

- https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-25842
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=480183
- https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-list/2009-January/msg00101.html

Based on the information above I've tried

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
```

in addtion to enabling and disabling the different "channels".

Anybody knows the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in RHN and it's CDN, where it is saying "XYZ" is the checksum for file A but when yum does a checksum on what it has downloaded it's not getting "XYZ" so refuses to use it.

I'd highly recommend you open a support ticket, or you can just wait for it to fix itself.

You probably want to link your support ticket to:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638922

...which is where the current problem is being collected.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. Red Hat support told me to disable location aware updates. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `yum makecache`?

Comment: Tried it now. Same thing happened again.

Comment: "yum makecache" is just an even more expensive way of doing "yum clean all". The cheapest fix is "yum clean expire-cache" ... but none of those things will fix this kind of problem.

Comment: Yea it fixed "/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum" for me (using a custom local repo)